# How to setup the function to retrieve a content generated from another script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a plugin which replacing the icons on some page. The content on it appearing after DOM Loaded, so the document.ready method will not work. The content is table rows in a `<tbody>` element which generated by another script running, it has the function called **renderRow** which appending the rows to the page. Every generated row with unique data-id attribute has sub-element `<div id=thumbnail>` where icon is located.

So the structure is next:

```
<tbody id="content">
  //generated content there
  <tr data-id="123">
    <td id="selection">
    <td>
    <td id="ui-draggable">
       <div id="thumbnail" style="......."></div>
    <td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Is it possible / are you willing to modify the "another scipt"? Depending on this, you have mulptiple possible options, so the question is a bit broad

Comment: No, I'm not allowed to edit other script, as well I've tried the jQuery function **.on**  to try to capture the execution of renderRow  function but it didn't worked out

Comment: No, that wouldn't do the trick, as `renderRow` will be called separately for each row, so multiple times. You can use a `setInterval` to wait for the content to be added, but selecting rows succeeding will not be a guarantee that the operation is finished and all rows are added. Is there a criteria that can be used to know it's finished (another change in the DOM, a global javascript variable, anything?)

Comment: But we don't know for sure how long it would take on different computers and with different workload to process it, ```setInterval``` not solving it at all. So my idea is somehow track the filling of the ```<tbody>``` and listen to it's changes

Comment: `setInterval` can do the trick, on contrary to `setTimeout` the function would be called again and again until you detect the table is filled, you just need to find a criteria and not forget to clear the interval when it's ok. You can also use a [mutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the table but it will be fired on every single change made on what you listen. Again, the answer is subjective and depends on informations we don't have. It depends on the script

Comment: Oh, nice idea with ```MutationObserver``` I will try it out!

Comment: @Kaddath I've managed to do this with ```MutationObserver```, it's works very good, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help